# Behat Test for media files

Tags: symfony, testing, behat

I want to test a video file. This video file appears a modal dialog. How can I test the functionality?

I could look for html video-tag like this:

```
$this->getSession()->getPage()->find("html", 'video');
```

but i want to test functionality of video playing.

Thanks.

Comment: How do you test a video is playing in php? you don't

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I most cases when a video is added into a page it will be included in an iframe.

What you could test is that the modal is opened and contains an iframe with the video.

You could try to play the video, which will not help since you would need to use some external api's to see if the video is really playing, but this is an overkill.

Comment: Thx. :)
How could i test this html-attribute:
`style="padding-right: 17px;"`

Comment: after find method you have getAttribute('attribute_name') to get the attribute value, after you can use any php method for checking the text and throw exception if not found